# How do I know if a Facebook user id is a global uid or an app-scoped user id (ASID)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Facebook is requiring access tokens to query profile photos based on user id beginning October 24, 2020.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture#requirements-change

They recommend appending breaking_change=profile_picture to the URL, but I have a lot of user ids which makes testing each id problematic. How do I know which will require an access token in the future and which are currently app-scoped and will NOT need an additional access token?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to determine whether an id is app scoped, user ids fall in the range (id < 2200000000 || (id >= 100000000000000 && id <= 100099999989999). App scoped user ids will fall outside of this range

The code below is 10 years old, but the ranges still appear to be used:
https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-js-sdk/blob/deprecated/src/xfbml/helper.js#L37

I have tested quite a few user ids as close as possible to those boundaries and found the statements in this answer to be accurate.

To clarify, user ids that will need additional authorization fall within the above mentioned range. Just because an ID returned by Facebook's API falls outside of this range does NOT indicate that it is an app-scoped ID. It could be the ID of a post, comment, etc. If you know that an ID corresponds to a user and falls outside this range, you can assume that it is already app scoped.

For further reference, non-app-scoped user ids were returned from Facebook's APIs [prior to v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#app-scoped-ids). Apps that were not upgraded prior to April 30, 2015 were automatically upgraded. After the upgrade to v2.0 "The ID will not change for people who already logged into your app. It will remain locked as the user's original Facebook ID." So the API can still return a non-app-scoped ID for users that used your app prior to the upgrade (even as recently as 2020).